# Proof involving upper or lower triangular matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

Prove that if $A$ and $B$ are both upper or lower triangular matrices, then the diagonal entries of both $AB$ and $BA$ are the products of the diagonal entries.

**Attempt.** Assuming the dimensions of matrices A and B allow their product to be successfully computed. I don't know how to go about this proof after this step.

**Hint.** I want the solution to this problem to be a simple as possible, while using techniques that are elementary by nature. So please, no definition of Matrix Multiplication or Summations. Thanks!

Comment: I think you should change upper and lower triangular matrices to upper or lower triangular matrices.

Comment: Done @TheGeekGreek

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint.** Try to use the multiplication formula for matrices (if they are of appropriate sizes) $$(AB)_{ij} = \sum_{k = 1}^n A_{ik}B_{kj}$$ and consider the case where $j = i$ to get the diagonal entries.

Comment: Is there an easier or less tedious way to do this than to use summations

Comment: I really believe this is the easiest way to do the job. You only want diagonals, so the sum tells you what to do.

Comment: @JoseDosSantos Yes, I think it is the easiest one. A less tedious way would just be to say, that this is trivial.